# How to export ReactJS + Typescript component for Vanilla JS and HTML

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have one of ReactJS component and its sub-components styled with css. I would you like to export my component for VanillaJS and HTML. Is there any easier way for it ?

I don't want to import react@17 or 18 into HTML.

Or I am open for any other suggestions instead of ReactJS

I tried to run "react-scripts eject" it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with below steps

run `npm run build`

after than, you will get build folder into your project directory. Copy main.XXXX.js file and import it to HTML via script tag. Do same thing for your css file.